# Sci-fi first-person shooter set in the future: father dies saving kid, kid is saved by a captain, final mission is to kill the president

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I can't remember the name of this game, but it had to be between 2015–2017. The game was like an adventure sci-fi first-person shooter in a future world. The story was about a father who saved his kid and then was killed by the enemies of the good guys, but the kid was saved by a captain, a soldier, or someone else. The good guys had, like, a white-and-blue uniform, and the bad ones had black and red. The player character also had a drone, for which I could change the drone's abilities. I can also remember that the final mission was about stealthily killing the good president for revenge.

Answer (score 15):

[*Killzone Shadow Fall*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killzone_Shadow_Fall)

- Released in 2013, so close to your timeline.
- First person shooter which takes place in the near future (the year 2370) and on a different planet (named Vekta).
- In the first mission, the player character is a young boy whose father attempts to help him escape enemy territory, and the father dies in the process. The boy was saved by a soldier (a "shadow marshal", which is the source of "shadow" in the game's title).
- The boy grew up to become a shadow marshal as well, and has a drone (which can be seen on the cover art).
- The "good guys" are the Vektans with blue highlights, and the "bad guys" are the Helghast who wear black and red.
- The final mission was a stealth assassination mission of a Vektan, but not of the president. The target was

> the shadow marshal who rescued the boy in the first mission.

Comment: You even have the Helgast emblem to go with it! :D

Comment: @paddotk I believe you're the first user on SE to recognize the emblem. :)